# Plots change if variables are rearranged

Tags: graphing-functions

I have the following equation which I believe is approximately valid for my dataset.

$$\frac{L\sin\beta}{s_i} = A\left(\frac{\sin\beta}{RE\cos\beta}\right)^{0.5}$$

where L, $\beta, s_i$, and RE are variables (RE is the Reynolds number); $A$ is a constant.

If I plot the left hand side versus the right hand side without the constant $A$ included on the RHS, I get a reasonably good fit with an $R^2$ valued of $0.939$.  However, if I divide both sides by $\sin\beta$, the fit is poor with an R squared value of $0.677$.

$$\frac{L}{s_i} = A\left(\frac{1}{RE\sin\beta \cos\beta}\right)^{0.5}$$

Is this happening because $\sin\beta$ is a variable?  The reason I want to divide by $\sin\beta$ is because I think it makes more sense from a physical explanation of the phenomena that has lead to this approximate equation.

Comment: What is measured and what are the constants ?

Comment: L, si, $\beta$, and Re are measured or calculated from other variables.  A is constant.

Comment: Sorry, but "plot the LHS vs the RHS"? Please identify which one variable you are plotting against which other single variable.